# C# return int and increase value after return

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property that receive an `int`, and each get Number will return the `int` and then I need to increase the `int` by one.
If i do like this:

```
    public int Number
    {
        set;
        get
        {
            Number++;
            return Number;
        }
    }
```

Its not good since if i start with 7000, it will start with 7001.
How can i increase after the return ?

Can I use `return Number++;` ?

Comment: have you even tried your own suggestion? stackoverflow is not your personal debugger army.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid doing this.

The first best practice about properties is *consistency*, i.e. your proprety shouldn't modify a member of your class when the getter is called. Basically, multiple consecutive calls to the getter should return the same value (there are exceptions, for example `DateTime.Now`, but those are edge cases).

If you want to compute an operation (increment in your case), you probably should use a function.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx):

> In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data.
>   Properties are used like fields, meaning that properties should not be
>   computationally complex **or produce side effects**.

The first side effect you could see is the debugger that would silently increment your number in case you have a watch on your property...

Answer (score 7):

First, your current code will throw [StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Why? Because it will return `Number`, but to return the `Number` it will read the `Number` value. So it will call `get` infinitely.

Second, Use [Postfix increment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691363%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to solve your main problem.

Try this:

```
    private int number;

    public int Number
    {
        set { number = value; }
        get
        {
            return number++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile, you can't mix auto properties with manually created properties.